# Get all types from formly config

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I am trying to make a dynamic form creation system using formly and i'm trying to work out if there is a way to get a list of all the formly types that are set in the config. There is a formlyConfig.getType() but that is only for a single type is there a way to get all of the formly types